# How to get ruby to open input file and capture input on save

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am making a rails generator, and instead of passing a filename as an argument, I would like it to open in a terminal editor, and once I save a file, read that file and continue.

This is similar to how git commit works. When I do git commit, it opens a file, I save, and it continues, but I'm not sure how I can go about doing the same thing in ruby. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
def tmp_path
  t = Time.now.utc.strftime '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
  "/tmp/#{t}_generator_crud_#{_namespace '_'}#{_table_name}_table"
end

path     = tmp_path
path     = Rails.root.join('lib','generators','templates','config.erb.yml').to_s
template = Erubis::Eruby.new File.read(path)
content  = template.result namespace:  _namespace,
                           table_name: _table_name
File.open(path, 'w'){|f|f.write content}
system 'vi', path
config = YAML.load_file path
```